# Highslide cannot expand image(full screen size) in colorbox (iframe mode)

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, highslide

I made popup layer using Colorbox(iframe mode), and the Colorbox's iframe has HTML page.
and I added Highslide in the HTML page.

This is the code of Colorbox

```
$("a.colorbox_photo_view").colorbox({
  iframe:true, 
  width:"600",
  height:"800",
  scrolling:true,
  overlayClose:false,
  escKey:false,
  opacity:0.7
});
```

and HTML page (in Colorbox's iframe) has this HTML code.

```
<a href="photo.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
  <img src="photo.jpg" width="550px"></img>
</a>
```

actually, photo.jpg is width=3648px, height=2056px

When I click the photo, photo cannot be expanded my monitor'full screen (1280x1024).
just expanded as width(600px) in iframe size.

How can I make photo expanded my monitor's full screen in Colorbox popup layer?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do.  The page within the iframe cannot expand beyond the size of that iframe.  Try using another method of loading your colorbox - in a div for example.